# Hibernate Search breaks with Spring Boot 2.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-search

When i migrated one of my Hibernate Search project from Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE to 2.3.0.RELEASE, application started facing deadlock during the very startup.

I can not see any error in the logs either.

My sample project is here:
https://github.com/cancerian0684/listing-service

If i rollback Spring Boot 2.3.0 to 2.2.7, everything started working fine again. Is there a known issue in using Hibernate Search (tried both 5.x and 6.0.0.Beta8) with Spring Boot 2.3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.3 switched to deferred JPA initialization and that leads to some issue, Hibernate Search being one of them. You should be able to get it back working using the following property

```
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16230#issuecomment-634013371) for some more context.

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot! I was debugging this deadlock Spring/Hibernate issue for some time already.